# Add Strongly Typed List to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to add some entries to a database in a controllers HTTP post event.  However I am getting the following error:

> The entity type 'List' was not found. Ensure that the
>   entity type has been added to the model.

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Name,Weight)] List<WBLoading> wBLoading)  
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Entry(wBLoading).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(wBLoading);
}
```

I have added the table to the DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Models.WBLoading> WBLoading { get; set; }
```

Model:

```
public class WBLoading
{
    public int ID { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the following code.

```
_context.WBLoading.add(wBLoading);    
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Even if you think you gave the right answer, you should explain how it works to solve the problem instead of just posting code sample.

Comment: That gives me a compile error:  `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Ao.Models.WBLoading>' to 'Ao.Models.WBLoading'`

Comment: user _context.WBLoading.AddRange(wBLoading); method,

Comment: That now compiles fine but it gives me the same original error on the line `_context.Entry(wBLoading).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Ok, I just removed the line in question and now it works  - thanks.

Comment: what you want to do like if you want to add entries in the table then remove this line or if you want to update all the entries then use this statement.

Comment: Ok, I just removed the line in question and now it works  - thanks.